# How to deal with a massive amount of conditions

Tags: c#, design-patterns

**Intro**

I am trying to build a system that will give information to the front-end which elements should and shouldn’t be shown.

But the problem i am running into is that i have to deal with massive amount of conditions, these could vary from rights to which modules are available and even which data is available.

So i was expecting that someone else would also have run in to this problem, but i couldn’t find anything.

**What i have tried**

I first start searching for design patterns that could possibly deal with this problem but i couldn’t find any that did. Then i went to source making and read all the descriptions of possible patterns but to me none of them seemed to be the solution to my problem.

Afterwards i just searched around if someone had encounter a similar problem and once again i did not seem to find any close comparisons to my problem.

So are their any suggestion how i could improve searching 
Or did i overlook something?

Comment: There is no general rule for this. As your system grows your requirements will also. So what you decide today is probably whrong tomorrow.

Comment: The solution isn't about C#, maybe SQL based.

You have to make a logic on your DB for permissions, it isn't anything new and you can find 9219149491349 examples about it on the web

Comment: Do it somehow, then show complete piece of code on [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Asking *in advance* is tempting, but is unlikely to give you answer you expect.

Comment: @Sinatr
I wasn't searching for literal answer, just some suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you take a look to something like the [Rules design pattern](https://www.michael-whelan.net/rules-design-pattern/)

Effectively, this would be a large set of predicates.

Steps needed to accomplise this:

```
1. Change boolean logic to predicates and extentions
2. Create interfaces that provide the proper logic and transformations
```

> With the Rules Pattern there is an Evaluator class that loops through a collection of rules and executes them. It evaluates the result and decides what action to take. In the simplest case it just executes all the rules, but it is also possible to add some selection logic to each rule that allows the Evaluator class to decide whether or not to run the rule (such as the IsMatch() method on the IRule interface above).

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `if` statements into method which return `bool` value. For example:

```
public void GetMeal(Behavior behavior)
{
    if (isAnimal(behavior))
        GetMilk();
    else
        ChangeBattery();
}


private bool isAnimal(Behavior behavior)
{
    if (behavior.HasVoice 
        && behavior.HasVoice 
        && !behavior.HasBattery )
        return true;

    return false;
}


public class Behavior 
{
    public bool HasVoice { get; set; }
    public bool HasName { get; set; }
    public bool HasBattery { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest replacing those statements with commands. Here is a link with more info. The code is not in C# tho but I think you can understand the main idea from it.

https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/refactorings/replace-conditional-dispatcher-with-command

Comment: This question is so braod and unspecific, that it´s unlikely that your answer covers everything.